# Git: show state for all files, even unchanged/ignored

Tags: git

I'm in a directory that is ignored, but some files are tracked. I want to find out which are already tracked and which not.

What `git` command to use to see the state of every file (in this working copy directory), even if it is unchanged or ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You looking for [ls-files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files)

`git ls-files -t -c -o`

Comment: Hm, with the `-i`option I'm getting the error `fatal: ls-files --ignored needs some exclude pattern`. Without it, some files are shown. The best options seem to be `git ls-files -t -c -o`.